# React Native: Is there a way to get console.logs saved to log file on device?

Tags: react-native, logging, error-logging, logfile, error-log

In my React Native app, I want to be able to take all the console.logs and thrown errors and have them saved to a log file on the device running the app, so that the user can retrieve and send me the file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think its possible out of the box. You might need to extend your console object and use AsyncStorage API to write into a file on the user's device.

Comment: This is what I use for my app (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) log tracking system on your app.